# video full screen with all controls disabled

Tags: iphone, video-encoding

I have a video that needs to be activated when scanning a qr-code. When starting a video needs to be shown full-screen and without controls (volume and other buttons). Is there a code for this? Also is it possible to disable all functions of the iphone, so the user needs to view the full video? I would be so greatfull f somebody would answer me..

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `controlStyle` property of an MPMoviePlayerController to **MPMovieControlStyleNone**. You'll have a fullscreen movie with no controls. Just remember to set the delegate so you can dismiss the video when it finishes playing.